# How to update my view when a subsequent JavaScript file is need to produce the proper HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, owl-carousel

I use `$http.get()` to get my model `$scope.workoutData` and the object is fine as I can see in my `console.log(data)` output. However my view is not loading as if it has received the model. Once the model is updated, I need to also run the `owlCarousel()` [FROM HERE](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/). This function adds elements and classes to my html behind the scenes. I've tried using `$scope.$apply();` in the places where you see it commented out.

```
 app.controller('calendarCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

  //Hard coding like this works just fine when I remove the $http.get() request
  //$scope.workoutData = {"1969-12-31":[["14:50:15","1","8","135",null].... 

  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $http.get("php/getWorkoutData.php")
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data); // show that I have a proper object
        $scope.workoutData = data;
    });

    //$scope.$apply();
    var owl = $("#owl-demo");

    // This needs to run after the model updates
    owl.owlCarousel({
        itemsCustom : [
            [0, 2],
            [500, 3],
            [1000, 4],
            [1600, 5]
        ],
        navigation : true
    });
    //$scope.$apply();
  });
}]);
```

Here is my html:

```
            <div id="calendar" ng-controller="calendarCtrl">
                <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <div class="item" ng-repeat="(date, figures) in workoutData">
                        <div class="scollHeader">
                            {{date}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="scrollBody">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Time</th>
                                        <th>Exercise</th>
                                        <th>Reps</th>
                                        <th>Weight</th>
                                        <th>Location</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="set in figures">
                                        <td ng-repeat="dataPoint in set track by $index">{{dataPoint}}</td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

but `owlCalousel()` changes it to this (when I hard code it)

[image]

**How can I get my View to update properly?**

Comment: Can you post your `html` code as well?

Answer (score 0):

What about placing the owl code into the success callback like this?

```
$http.get("php/getWorkoutData.php")
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // show that I have a proper object
    $scope.workoutData = data;

    // This needs to run after the model updates
    owl.owlCarousel({
      itemsCustom : [
        [0, 2],
        [500, 3],
        [1000, 4],
        [1600, 5]
      ],
      navigation : true
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular-owl-carousel](https://github.com/jonahbron/angular-owl-carousel). It creates a directive to populate an owl carousel with data retrieved from a controller.